# wwwroot static files can be routed but can't be accessed inside cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, razor-pages

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project. The API is responsible for generating some HTML-based documents and sending them through email.

Documents should contain some images, so in order to use them I've added `wwwroot` folder to the project, placed images inside, and registered middleware `app.UseStaticFiles()`.

```
wwwroot
  * images
      img.png
```

When I route to images, it's working fine, `https://localhost:56180/images/img.png`.

But when I try to use them inside the `.cshtml` file, it can not be loaded.

My `.cshtml` files location:

```
wwwroot
Templates
    Shared
       SomeFiles.cshtml
    SomeOtherFiles.cshtml
```

Accessing images:

```
<img src="~/images/img.png" />
```

**UPDATE**

This is a Web API that serves as a Restful service. And responsible for building documents and sending them as text to the next email API service.

Process:

- build `.cshtml` file with provided values
- read `.cshtml` file as a string
- compile it using a razor engine (IRazorEngine)
- send string template to next email api

Received email:
[image]

Emails are received, and everything is fine, just can not load static images from `wwwroot` folder

- OS: Windows 10
- Using Visual Studio
- Application will be hosted in azure kubernetes

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: when you render your view, it will be under once controller method, it will consider application domain if you write `<img src="~/images/img.png" />`. But when you sent mail that will not be possible need to send entire URL of the image. like way Understand the way how u reference styles with in the application and outside application.

Comment: @UpenderReddy didn't get your thoughts

Comment: SMTP sending mail is Responsible for sending plain text `~` sign Represents application domain where HTML is rendered. Inspect the mail you have received you may get conclusion.

Comment: uh, yeah. I'm converting html docs to strings before sending them, receiving emails with all expectations only without images,

Comment: Check `<img />` tage you will understand

Comment: " try to use them inside the .cshtml file, it can not be loaded."You mean you cannot load the .cshtml file ?

Comment: can not load image,

Comment: Could you share your .cshtml file route? And how you define the route of razor pages ? So that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: .cshtml has no route, this service is a Restful service, I'm using .cshtml file only to build beautiful documents and read them as text, and sending to next an email API.

Comment: @QingGuo updated the question, if you get confused let me now

Comment: Is the`img.png` in the `wwwroot folder` of the Received email project ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254418/discussion-between-maruf-and-qing-guo).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your idea, you use a razor page, to control the content with c# language, in that case you can't directly access the content by placing the name "SomeFiles.cshtml" in the url, you must create a controller to access the "SomeFiles" view .cshtml" like this "https://localhost:56180/images/MyFilePreview"

Comment: there is no need for a controller to access that image

Comment: static files do not require a controller.  You only need to use a controller when deploying dynamic content.  Static is simply accessed like it's in the file system.  You are correct that a cshtml file needs a controller, however I think you misunderstood the question.  He's trying to reference an image from inside a cshtml file that has a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below code in your Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
...
app.MapRazorPages();
```

And add Pages folder:

[image]

result:
[image]

Comment: oh, if this is the solution (not checked yet) I didn't want to add additional folders & files

Comment: @Maruf   I mean we need put files into the Pages folder, so that we can load the  .cshtml file.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited this answer.  I didn't apparently notice that your problem was the image wasn't showing up in an email.  You're probably getting blocked by the email client.  Email clients by default block remotely accessed images for various reasons, but mainly for tracking prevention.
You need to embed your image directly in the email if you want it to just work out of the box.
I didn't write this code myself.  It comes from here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/326346/How-to-embed-a-image-in-email-body

```
MailMessage Mail = new MailMessage();        

Mail.From = new MailAddress("myemail@bogusdomain.com");
Mail.To.Add("hisemail@bogusdomain.com");
Mail.Subject = "This is Image Test.";
Mail.Body = "This is the body of the email";
LinkedResource LinkedImage = new LinkedResource(@"J:\My 
Documents\Advika1.jpg");
LinkedImage.ContentId = "MyPic";
LinkedImage.ContentType = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);

AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("You should see image next to this line. <img src=cid:MyPic>", null, "text/html");

htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(LinkedImage);
Mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

Hopefully you can rip what you need (the specific part of embedding the image) out of this.
Your html will have to be modified to use the cid reference as above.

Comment: is `yourfilename` here, my `.cshtml` file? if so, they are many files

Comment: it's the file the console output will list.  That function gets the entire path of the file but unfortunately it also has the file name in it.  It will absolutely not be .cshtml.  It will probably be a dll file in your case.  If you can't see console out you can change that to something else such as debug out which will output to the debug output in the IDE.  Probably the simplest solution would be just to put a breakpoint there and look at the value in the path variable.

Comment: I wonder, if the directory location is wrong, how routing is working? `https://localhost:56180/images/img.png`. Anyway, trying out your solution, will get back

Comment: I just noticed you said you were able to navigate directly to the file in the browser.  That changes everything.  What path to the file shows up when you right-click and inspect on the broken image?  What does the browser console show for errors?

Comment: yes, I'm able to navigate in the browser. Unfortunately, I can not inspect the browser, because it's not on the web page, it's compiled razor page coming to email as a message

Comment: let's change the question, what is the best approach to storing images statically and using them inside the application? Maybe a .resx file?

Comment: you should be able to redirect that to gmail or even outlook.  Alternately, just as a test, you can just print the url in plaintext in the email and we can see what the problem is.  Static files like the way you set your page up ARE the correct way, and if you can access them with the url they are being presented.  The problem MUST be that it's not compiling the url right.

Comment: I changed my answer completely.  I apparently missed the part originally where you said that it was not showing up in an email.  That's a setting in the email client and you'll have to work around it.

Comment: Looks like this is what I'm looking for, let me check and come back